# JS ES6 Destructuring, assign entire object and destructure its properties at the same time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to assign and destructure at the same time

```
a = {x: 1, y: 5}
let b, {x} = a
```

result:

```
b = undefined
x = 1
```

I want:

```
b = {x: 1, y: 5}
x = 1
```

Is there any way to achieve that ? When I try to assign with `const`

```
const c, {y} = a
      ^
Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration
```

Comment: `const b = a, {x} = a`? Although that doesn't *copy* the object.

Comment: let a = {x: 1, y: 5}
let b = {x} = a;

Comment: @RaviAshara that creates an implicit  global `x` (which throws an error in strict mode)

Comment: If you want a shallow copy. `const b = {...a}, {x} = a`

Comment: Assigning multiple variables in a single expression is confusing enough. Adding destructuring on top is even worse. You might like it, most of your colleagues won't. If I see something like that, I will immediately refactor it. Please, have mercy to others.

Comment: `const { b = a, x } = a;`Assign the default value `a` to `b`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap `a` in an object and destructure `a` with a renaming to `b` and take the nested `x` directly.

```js
const
    a = { x: 1, y: 5 },
    { a: b, a: { x } } = { a };

console.log(b);
console.log(x);
```